# Offering monetary incentives to complete question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, incentive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Edit out an offer of financial reward. Right or wrong?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42767/edit-out-an-offer-of-financial-reward-right-or-wrong)

This is the question... in question: [How can I make DIVs flyout in response to a hover event (like the National Geographic site) using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744388/jquery-flyout-divs-on-hover)

It's a fairly standard question about Javascript and jQuery, and the OP has gone to some length to describe his problems, but this part here, [added in an edit 7 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/b0d09bad-7e92-4a66-9c35-05b0ab711a71/view-source), sort of worries me

> I know this is a tall order, and **I CAN
>   PAY** for a solution, and would be happy
>   to share the solution here as well so
>   others might benefit. You can email me
>   at kieradavenport@gmail.com if you're
>   interested in payment (I don't want to
>   clutter up answers/comments here with
>   inquisitions about payment).

Should we allow people to offer monetary rewards for answering a question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It effectively transforms the question into a job posting. Which *isn't* appropriate.

I don't think the author here was trying to abuse the site, he's just new - as Pekka notes, this is (sadly) common on some forums, where they're usually ignored.

However this being SO, I just edited it out. SO: 1, Forums: 0...

Answer (score 7):

There are already other sites for paid freelancing. I believe Stack Overflow shouldn't have anything to do with money.

Answer (score 2):

I would ignore them.

Requests like that are usually ignored by the general public, and find a solution the normal (free) way most of the time.

Only if somebody really relentlessly tries to use SO questions as a hiring platform for short-term jobs  would I report it to moderators and/or ask the OP to quit.