# Offer to do something for money on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

I stumbled across an answer on Stack Overflow that said something like:

> Hey, you could do that by using XXXXXXX, but if you get really stuck,
>   I could do that for you in exchange of a small fee.

Is it ok for answerers to try and charge money in exchange for more help? Or is this unacceptable behavior?

Comment: Flag it as spam.  This isn't rent a coder, and it's likely that they've posted similar answers elsewhere, so it's important not to simply edit it, but notify the moderators.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42767/edit-out-an-offer-of-financial-reward-right-or-wrong

Comment: @random - those questions are subtly different - is can an asker offer a reward and the other is can an answerer demand/request one. Pekka's answer seems to illustrate that those have (possibly) different issues at the edge cases.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Generally, it's not acceptable (although I can imagine edge cases where it *might* be okay - e.g. somebody giving an OP plenty of one-on-one tech support in comments, but after an hour's time giving up and saying "sorry, this is more time than I can give away for free".)

Either way, it's definitely not acceptable as a part of an answer, and as awoodland mentions above, it may even be eligible for a spam flag. Downvote and comment as you please.

If somebody wants to solicit small freelance jobs through Stack Overflow, they should post a notice on their profile that they can be hired, and then be generally helpful. It works! I've been contacted this way  numerous times already - even though I show no indication in my profile that I am interested in such offers, and I usually have to decline.

Answer (score 12):

Unacceptable IMHO. Edit it out or flag it for attention or perhaps even spam. There are other places for rentacoders. This is certainly not the place.

Comment: I'd possibly even go as far as to flag it as spam, depending on the context - it's unsolicited self promotion. (I.e. is there sufficient other content to make an edit worthwhile and is it a regular pattern by the user?)

Comment: @awoodland agree. Updated my answer.