# Is it permitted to solicit an expert for work, alongside a detailed technical [not IT-related] question?

Tags: discussion

Unlike as in this question: [Offer to do something for money on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121938/offer-to-do-something-for-money-on-stack-overflow), where an *answerer* offers to assist further with paid work, my question pertains to the *asker* offering paid work for help with a 1-off technical problem. I don't believe such a question has been asked on MSE before.

The issue has been raised in the past - specifically in relation to Stack Overflow - that SE does not want the site to turn into a feeding frenzy over $1.35 "code me a unicorn" tasks. It's an open site with a wealth of technical information and shared knowledge; and I want it to stay that way!

Here's my problem: [Pipe seized to inaccessible coupling - how to attach a new pipe?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2684/pipe-seized-to-inaccessible-coupling-how-to-attach-a-new-pipe)

I'm a programmer. This is a question I've been asked to post on behalf of a friend who doesn't use computers. It's a technical problem, and whatever the answer is, I'll post it if nobody else does when I find it out... but it's to do with a critical industrial machine being down.

Is it therefore acceptable for me to have written this at the bottom of the [detailed] question:

> Also if a UK expert in laundry steam operations sees this and you think you can fix this on-site for him, this is something he is interested in. He understands there is a cost involved, but the machinery is currently down and needs urgently repairing.

The accepted answer of the initial question I mentioned - of an *answerer* offering to do work for money - says this, by the way:

> Generally, it's not acceptable (although I can imagine edge cases where it might be okay).

I'm more curious to know the community's opinion, if I'm honest. If it's unacceptable, I'm quite happy to remove it.

Comment: I think reaction to this might be site specific, so asking on the appropriate meta might be the right approach.  But in general, I think soliciting paid help within the question seems contrary to the idea of being a repository of good questions and answers.  Soliciting via comments might be *more* acceptable since they are 3rd class citizens and can get cleaned up more easily.

Answer (score 5):

I think there are several problems with such a text.

The first one is that it attracts spam. You don't want people to answer it with 'call me here', 'see our company web site X', etc. Those 'answers' don't answer the question and harm the quality of the site.

Another problem is this. The SE model consists of questions and answers. Nothing more. Such 'fluff' only bury the actual question.

SE is a wonderful place to find answers, and there are a lot of experts. Therefore it is an excellent place to find experts. I would suggest to take that subject out of the question and move it to chat. You could take a look in one of the chat rooms available on your site. Usually, the experts can be found there too.