# Is it alright to pay real money for useful help?

Tags: support, incentive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Offering actual money as a bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25615/offering-actual-money-as-a-bounty)

I'm really stuck. My post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712365/cant-configure-mysql-datasource-in-gwt-hibernate-mysql-project) isn't getting any help yet. I'd be thrilled to pay a few bucks for a solution. I'm thinking of posting the following. But before I do, this seems like a good place to check first to see if something like this is ok. So, would the post below be ok?

---

I've been working on solving the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712365/cant-configure-mysql-datasource-in-gwt-hibernate-mysql-project) for too long. I will pay $40 to the first person who provides the answer I need to fix the problem.  Yes, real actual money for real help.

The conditions of my offer are:

- Yes, you'll just have to trust me to actually pay up. But you can - I'm good for it.
- You'll need a PayPal account where I can send you the money.
- I'll pay the first person to post a usable solution. I'm the sole judge on who's first and what I consider usable.
- When I have a usable solution, I'll post a reply inviting the person providing the answer to email me their PayPal account info so I can pay you.
- If you're skeptical (very reasonable) feel free to email me at the above address if you'd like reassurance that  my offer is real.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not paying people to answer your questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not/128584#128584).  Period.  And if that ever changes, I'll immediately delete all of my Stack Exchange accounts.

Comment: -1: Came here expecting a story about your poor son who is doing the missionary on a missionary in Nigera and needed my help to transfer funds from the US that a wealthy man left behind when he died. I am disappoint.

Comment: Not a dupe, the other one is feature request asking to integrate cash into the bounty system this one is just a discussion.

Answer (score 20):

I totally appreciate your willingness to reward people's efforts, but offers of money are extremely frowned upon on Stack Overflow for various reasons - mainly out of the fear that allowing them would introduce very harmful dynamics into the community (ie. people tearing each others' eyes out for the $$$). If you're interested in previous discussion on the subject, see e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25615/offering-actual-money-as-a-bounty) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57850/pay-money-to-so-for-quick-support).

You will have to look elsewhere in this specific regard.

That said, [@Makoto is giving great advice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133793/138112) on how to improve your question in order to get help within the normal Stack Overflow system. If something good comes out of it, you can still offer a gift afterwards to those user(s) who helped you most.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to pay for help, hire a legitimate programmer.  Stack Overflow isn't the place for that.

You can do some of the following to get the attention of others, though:

- Clarify and pinpoint **what you think is wrong** with your code.  In other words, show the effort that you've tried to fix this on your own, but are really stuck.
- Revise your question so **it reads clearer** for those that are reading it.
- **Appropriately tag** your question so that people from certain walks of life can help you with your question.  I'm not noticing [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), which could help.
- With 75 reputation, you can **place a bounty** on your question.  It doesn't guarantee that it will be answered, but people may be more inclined to look at bountied questions.

Comment: " hire a legitimate programmer. Stack Overflow isn't the place for that." - outdated advice now that SO has the whole "careers" website.

Comment: No; Stack Overflow *still* isn't appropriate to want to hire someone.  Careers *is*.  You shouldn't be asking a question that either offers a cash reward, or links to a Careers entry.  The latter would just be tacky.

Comment: I consider all of SE just one "big 'ol website"; from that perspective, "careers" is an aspect of SO and therefore a place you can hire legit programmers.

Comment: If you post that as a question to the Stack Overflow main page, and blatantly ask to hire developers, you're going to have a bad time...